# How to get wifi signal informations : strength, Link speed on android studio?

Tags: android, android-activity, wifi, signal-strength, ssid

I used the folowing code but i still have problems, it doesn't return any informations :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //initializeWiFiListener();

    }

    public void initializeWiFiListener() {

        String connectivity_context = Context.WIFI_SERVICE;

        final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(connectivity_context);

        if (!wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {

            if (wifi.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING) {

                wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }
        }

      registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
                String ssid = info.getSSID();
                int rssi = info.getRssi();
                int speed = info.getLinkSpeed();
                TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                t1.setText(ssid + " " + Integer.toString(rssi) + " " + Integer.toString(speed));
            }

        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION));
    }

}
```

there is no informations about my connected wifi.

How to get wifi signal informations : strength, Link speed ?

Comment: What do you mean "there is no information"? Is `onReceive()` getting called? Have you added logging to check that? Have you requested permission `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` in the manifest?

Comment: I have already done that but when i called onReceive it shows me a failure !

Comment: Please explain. What failure do you see? What do the logs show? You shouldn't call `onReceive()` anyway, Android needs to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, call [`getConnectionInfo()` on `WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConnectionInfo%28%29), to get a `WifiInfo` object. On there, you have [`getRssi()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getRssi()) for signal strength and [`getLinkSpeed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getLinkSpeed()) for link speed.

Comment: I have already imported the android.net.wifi.WifiManager classe but didn't solve the problem.
Can you clarify your answer by a code. please !